# I keep getting error {"Input string was not in a correct format."}

Tags: c#, asp.net

I checked in Visual studio with debug both amtBidded and  ItemPrice have values of "xx.xx" with quotation marks around them as if they are strings  I would like to convert to a decimal or float.  The Parse keeps giving me "Input string was not in a correct format." error.   I tried the "culture" solutions  that were recommended and still get an error.

I am at a loss, any help would be appreciated.

```
protected void ButtonClicktoBid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String CurrentBidder = Context.User.Identity.GetUserName();
        String ItemId = ListBoxitemNum.SelectedItem.ToString();
        String ItemPrice = ListBoxCurrentPrice.SelectedItem.ToString();
        String amtBidded = TextBoxAmtBidded.Text.ToString();
        String SecondPlaceBidder = 
        ListBoxCurrentWinningBidder.SelectedItem.ToString();
        String dbMagic;

        if (float.Parse(amtBidded) < float.Parse(ItemPrice))
        {
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: `amtBidded` might not be abled to be converted to `float` successfully, try to use `TryParse`, that will return you the Boolean result and an converted output

Comment: What is the actual value of `amtBidded`?

Comment: Thank you both for your responses.  Rainman sent a solution that worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this;

```
    var currentCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    currentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
    if (float.Parse(amtBidded, NumberStyles.Any, currentCulture) < float.Parse(ItemPrice, NumberStyles.Any, currentCulture))
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: I am so thankful for that code.  It works flawlessly.  I am continually humbled by how strangers will take time out of their day to help.  I only hope to get good enough one day to return the favor.